# Two variable definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals, leibniz-integral-rule

Q) Let $f:R^+\rightarrow R$ be differentiable function with $f(1)=3$ and satisfying
$$\int_{1}^{xy}f(t)dt=y\int_{1}^{x}f(t)dt+x\int_{1}^{y}f(t)dt; \forall x,y\in R^+$$,
then $f(e)=?$

My Attempt:I tried Leibnitz Rule which states that
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_{\beta(x)}^{\alpha(x)}f(t)dt=f(\alpha(x))\frac{d\alpha(x)}{dx}-f(\beta(x))\frac{d\beta(x)}{dx}$$
but nothing useful seem to come out.

So, please help and $\mathcal THANKS\, IN\, ADVANCE!$

NOTE: ANSWER IS '6'

Comment: Differentiate again after Leibniz rule and plug in $x=1$ or $y=1$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating with respect to $x$ gives us $$f(xy)y=yf(x)+\int_1^yf(t)dt$$
Now we differentiate again, this time with respect to $y$, to get: $$f(xy)+f'(xy)xy=f(x)+f(y)$$
Now plug in $x=1$:
\begin{align*}
f(y)+f'(y)y&=3+f(y)\\
\implies f'(y)&=\frac{3}{y}\\
\implies f(y)&=3\log y+C
\end{align*}
As $f(1)=3$ we see $C=3$ and hence $f(e)=3+3=6$.